# Open csv into input stream

Tags: java, android, csv

Im trying to open up a csv file from
 http://openchargemap.org/api/service.ashx?output=csv&countrycode=US&maxresults=2000
Im trying to add this data into a SQLite3 Database. Get an instream from this csv file and then use StringToken to separate the values and insert into a db.

```
public InputStream connect2(String url){

    // Create the httpclient
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Prepare a request object
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response;

    // return string
    String returnString = null;
    InputStream instream = null;

    try {

        // Open the webpage.
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
            // Connection was established. Get the content. 
             //ByteArrayOutputStream i = (ByteArrayOutputStream) response.getEntity();
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
            // to worry about connection release

            if (entity != null) {

                instream = entity.getContent();




                // Close the stream.
                instream.close();
            }
        }
        else {
            // code here for a response other than 200.  A response 200 means the webpage was ok
            // Other codes include 404 - not found, 301 - redirect etc...
            // Display the response line.
            returnString = "Unable to load page - " + response.getStatusLine();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException  ex) {
        // thrown by line 80 - getContent();
        // Connection was not established
        returnString = "Connection failed; " + ex.getMessage();
    }
    return instream;
}
```

The code is getting caught at IO Exception ex Connection Failed; openchargemap.org

Comment: Do you realize that you are returning closed stream?  And post rhe stack trace plese.

Comment: Yea It never get gets to that line  response = httpclient.execute(httpget) gives it the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have to do with the fact that the CSV "Content-Disposition" is "attachment". You  might find the following useful:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Comment: So how would I go about handling that situation, any ideas?

Comment: Try using the example I sent instead to see if you can at least get the stream.